# Java NullPointerException javax.xml.transform

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception

I wrote a simple XMLPhoneBook program that get inputs such as firstname, lastname and phone number from user (from input console) and saves it into a XML file called "**PhoneBook.xml**". The program also checks for the existing xml file and updates the file if its already exist or else creates a new file. The first version my code I wrote without error handling class was successful.

When I tried to update my code with the Error Handling Class thats when I started getting NullPointerException from javax.xml.transform. I have posted both versions of my code below for your understanding.

**main class XMLPhoneBook without Error Handling.**

```
    /**
     *
     * @author Sanjayan Ravi
     */
    /**
     *
     * Class XMLPhoneBook is the Main Class that controls getContactInfo function and storeContactInfo.
     */
    public class XMLPhoneBook 
    {
        GetContactInformation gci;
        StoreContactInformation sci;

        XMLPhoneBook()
        {
            gci = new GetContactInformation();
        }
        /**
        *
        * getContactInfo function triggers the functions getFirstName, getLastName, getPhoneNumber of the GetContactInformation class.
        */
        void getContactInfo(){
            gci.getFirstName();
            gci.getLastName();
            gci.getPhoneNumber();
        }
        /**
        *
        * The variables FName, LName, PhoneNumber of the class GetContactInformation contains the user entered data, these values are passed to the class StoreContactInformation for creating/updating an XML file with user data.
        */
        void storeContactInfo(){
            sci = new StoreContactInformation(gci.FName,gci.LName,gci.PhoneNumber);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            XMLPhoneBook pb = new XMLPhoneBook();
            pb.getContactInfo();
            pb.storeContactInfo();
        }

    }
```

**Class GetContactInformation without Error Handling.**

```
    /**
    *
    * Class GetContactInformation is responsible for getting inputs from the user such as First Name, Last Name and Phone Number. 
    * The variables FName(String), LName(String), PhoneNumber(long) are used for containing the user data during run time.
    * The Variable reader(Scanner) is used for getting inputs from the user via the console.
    */
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class GetContactInformation {
        String FName;
        String LName;
        long PhoneNumber;
        Scanner reader;

        GetContactInformation(){
            FName=null;
            LName=null;
            PhoneNumber=0;
        }
        /**
         *
         * The function getFirstName prompts the user for this first name and gets the inputs from the console.
         * Then the value for the first name is passed to the function setFirstName.
         */
        void getFirstName(){
            System.out.println("Enter Your FirstName = ");
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            setFirstName(reader.nextLine());
        }
         /**
         *
         * The function getLastName prompts the user for this last name and gets the inputs from the console.
         * Then the value for the last name is passed to the function setLastName.
         */
        void getLastName(){
            System.out.println("Enter Your LastName = ");
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            setLastName(reader.nextLine());
        }
         /**
         *
         * The function getPhoneNumber prompts the user for this phone number and gets the inputs from the console.
         * Then the value for the phone number is passed to the function setPhoneNumber.
         */
        void getPhoneNumber(){
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter Your PhoneNumber = ");
                reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
                setPhoneNumber(Long.parseUnsignedLong(reader.nextLine()));
            }catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e){

            }

        }
        /**
         *
         * The function setFirstName assigns the value it receives to the variable FName.
         */
        String setFirstName(String FN){
           return  FName=FN;
        }
        /**
         *
         * The function setLastName assigns the value it receives to the variable LName.
         */
        String setLastName(String LN){
            return  LName=LN;
        }
         /**
         *
         * The function setPhoneNumber assigns the value it receives to the variable PhoneNumber.
         */
        long setPhoneNumber(long PN){
            return  PhoneNumber=PN;
        }
    }
```

**Last class StoreContactInformation without Error Handling.**

```
    /**
     *
     * The StoreContactInformation is responsible for storing the user data such as first name, last name and phone number into an XML file called PhoneBook.xml.
     * The StoreContactInformation first checks if the XML file already exist then if the file exist it simply updates the file or else creates a new XML file with the provided user data.
     *
     */
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
    import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;

    import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;

    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    public class StoreContactInformation {

        File f;
        String filePathString ;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory ;
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder ;
        Document doc;
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory;
        Transformer transformer;
        DOMSource source;
        StreamResult result;
        String FirstName;
        String LastName;
        long PhoneNumber;

        StoreContactInformation(String fn, String ln, long pn){

            filePathString="PhoneBook.xml"; //File Path is the current working directory. 
            f = new File(filePathString);
            FirstName=fn;
            LastName=ln;
            PhoneNumber=pn;
            docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                }
            catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) 
                {
                    pce.printStackTrace();
                } 
            transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            try 
                {
                    transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                }
            catch (TransformerException tfe)
                {
                    tfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            // check if the XML file exist already !        
            if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                //if exist
                UpdateXMLFile();
                WriteToXMLFile(); 
            }else{
                //if do not exist
                CreateXMLFile(); 
                WriteToXMLFile();
            } 

        }
        /**
        *
        * The function CreateXMLFile creates a new XML file if one doesn't exist already. 
        * The first set of data stored in the XML file is given the unique id="1".
        * The root element of the XML file is "ContactInformation" which contains child nodes "Contact" with there unique ids.
        * The element "contact further contains child nodes "FirstName","LastName" and "PhoneNumber".
        */
        void CreateXMLFile(){

            doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ContactInformation");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            Element contact = doc.createElement("Contact");
            rootElement.appendChild(contact);
            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue("1");
            contact.setAttributeNode(attr);
            Element firstname = doc.createElement("FirstName");
            firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(FirstName));
            contact.appendChild(firstname);
            Element lastname = doc.createElement("LastName");
            lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(LastName));
            contact.appendChild(lastname);
            Element PN = doc.createElement("PhoneNumber");
            PN.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(java.lang.Long.toString(PhoneNumber)));
            contact.appendChild(PN);

        }
        /**
        *
        * The function WriteToXMLFile is responsible for writing the data into output XML file "PhoneBook.xml".
        * WriteToXMLFile also formats the data to be written into pretty print way with INDENT spaces and line breaks etc.
        */
        void WriteToXMLFile(){
            try 
                {
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
                source = new DOMSource(doc);
                result = new StreamResult(new File(filePathString));
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                System.out.println("Contact Saved !");
                }
            catch (TransformerException tfe) 
                {
                    tfe.printStackTrace();

                }
        }
        /**
        *
        * The function UpdateXMLFile updates the existing XML file with the new user data.
        * The new set of user data gets a unique id for the element "Contact" which is calculated and generated by UpdateXMLFile.
        * 
        */
        void UpdateXMLFile(){
            try
            {
                doc = docBuilder.parse(filePathString);
            }catch(SAXException sae){

            }catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } 
            int AttrValue=1;
            Node ContactInfo = doc.getFirstChild();
            NodeList NumberChildNodes = ContactInfo.getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0;i<NumberChildNodes.getLength();i++)
                {            
                    Node n = NumberChildNodes.item(i);
                    if ("Contact".equals(n.getNodeName())) 
                        {
                            AttrValue+=1;
                        }     
                }            
        Element contact = doc.createElement("Contact");
        ContactInfo.appendChild(contact);
            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue(Integer.toString(AttrValue));
            contact.setAttributeNode(attr);
            Element firstname = doc.createElement("FirstName");
            firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(FirstName));
            contact.appendChild(firstname);
            Element lastname = doc.createElement("LastName");
            lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(LastName));
            contact.appendChild(lastname);
            Element PN = doc.createElement("PhoneNumber");
            PN.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(java.lang.Long.toString(PhoneNumber)));
            contact.appendChild(PN);

        }
    }
```

**The above code was my first version of the XMLPhoneBook and it is working fine :**

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Java\xml>java XMLPhoneBook
Enter Your FirstName =
XXXXXX
Enter Your LastName =
YYYYYY
Enter Your PhoneNumber =
789634569863
Contact Saved !
```

My problem started when i tried to update the above code with error handling class as show below.

**Main Class XMLPhoneBook which gets are exceptions:**

```
    /**
     *
     * @author Sanjayan Ravi
     */
    package xmlphonebook;
    /**
     *
     * Class XMLPhoneBook is the Main Class that controls getContactInfo function and storeContactInfo.
     */
    public class XMLPhoneBook 
    {
        GetContactInformation gci;
        StoreContactInformation sci;


        XMLPhoneBook()
        {
            gci = new GetContactInformation();

        }
        /**
        *
        * getContactInfo function triggers the functions getFirstName, getLastName, getPhoneNumber of the GetContactInformation class.
        */
        void getContactInfo()throws Exception {        
            gci.getFirstName();
            gci.getLastName();
            gci.getPhoneNumber();
        }
        /**
        *
        * The variables FName, LName, PhoneNumber of the class GetContactInformation contains the user entered data, these values are passed to the class StoreContactInformation for creating/updating an XML file with user data.
        */
        void storeContactInfo()throws Exception{             
            sci = new StoreContactInformation(gci.FName,gci.LName,gci.PhoneNumber);               
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            XMLPhoneBook pb = new XMLPhoneBook();
            try{
            pb.getContactInfo();
            pb.storeContactInfo();
            }catch(Exception e){
                ErrorHandler er = new ErrorHandler(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Class GetContactInformation :**

```
    package xmlphonebook;
    /**
    *
    * Class GetContactInformation is responsible for getting inputs from the user such as First Name, Last Name and Phone Number. 
    * The variables FName(String), LName(String), PhoneNumber(long) are used for containing the user data during run time.
    * The Variable reader(Scanner) is used for getting inputs from the user via the console.
    */
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class GetContactInformation {
        String FName;
        String LName;
        long PhoneNumber;
        Scanner reader;

        GetContactInformation(){
            FName=null;
            LName=null;
            PhoneNumber=0;
        }
        /**
         *
         * The function getFirstName prompts the user for this first name and gets the inputs from the console.
         * Then the value for the first name is passed to the function setFirstName.
         */
        void getFirstName()throws Exception{
            System.out.println("Enter Your FirstName = ");
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            setFirstName(reader.nextLine());
        }
         /**
         *
         * The function getLastName prompts the user for this last name and gets the inputs from the console.
         * Then the value for the last name is passed to the function setLastName.
         */
        void getLastName()throws Exception{
            System.out.println("Enter Your LastName = ");
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            setLastName(reader.nextLine());
        }
         /**
         *
         * The function getPhoneNumber prompts the user for this phone number and gets the inputs from the console.
         * Then the value for the phone number is passed to the function setPhoneNumber.
         */
        void getPhoneNumber()throws Exception{

            System.out.println("Enter Your PhoneNumber = ");
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
            setPhoneNumber(Long.parseUnsignedLong(reader.nextLine()));

        }
        /**
         *
         * The function setFirstName assigns the value it receives to the variable FName.
         */
        String setFirstName(String FN)throws Exception{
           return  FName=FN;
        }
        /**
         *
         * The function setLastName assigns the value it receives to the variable LName.
         */
        String setLastName(String LN)throws Exception{
            return  LName=LN;
        }
         /**
         *
         * The function setPhoneNumber assigns the value it receives to the variable PhoneNumber.
         */
        long setPhoneNumber(long PN)throws Exception{
            return  PhoneNumber=PN;
        }
    }
```

**class StoreContactInformation :**

```
    package xmlphonebook;
    /**
     *
     * The StoreContactInformation is responsible for storing the user data such as first name, last name and phone number into an XML file called PhoneBook.xml.
     * The StoreContactInformation first checks if the XML file already exist then if the file exist it simply updates the file or else creates a new XML file with the provided user data.
     *
     */
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
    import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

    import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


    public class StoreContactInformation {

        File f;
        String filePathString ;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory ;
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder ;
        Document doc;
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory;
        Transformer transformer;
        DOMSource source;
        StreamResult result;
        String FirstName;
        String LastName;
        long PhoneNumber;
        int choice;
        Scanner reader;
        OutputKeys OutputKeys;

        StoreContactInformation(String fn, String ln, long pn) throws Exception {

            filePathString="PhoneBook.xml"; //File Path is the current working directory. 
            f = new File(filePathString);
            FirstName=fn;
            LastName=ln;
            PhoneNumber=pn;
            docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            // check if the XML file exist already !        
            if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                //if exist
                UpdateXMLFile();
                WriteToXMLFile(); 
            }else{
                //if do not exist
                CreateXMLFile(); 
                WriteToXMLFile();
            } 


        }
        /**
        *
        * The function CreateXMLFile creates a new XML file if one doesn't exist already. 
        * The first set of data stored in the XML file is given the unique id="1".
        * The root element of the XML file is "ContactInformation" which contains child nodes "Contact" with there unique ids.
        * The element "contact further contains child nodes "FirstName","LastName" and "PhoneNumber".
        */
        void CreateXMLFile(){

            doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ContactInformation");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            Element contact = doc.createElement("Contact");
            rootElement.appendChild(contact);
            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue("1");
            contact.setAttributeNode(attr);
            Element firstname = doc.createElement("FirstName");
            firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(FirstName));
            contact.appendChild(firstname);
            Element lastname = doc.createElement("LastName");
            lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(LastName));
            contact.appendChild(lastname);
            Element PN = doc.createElement("PhoneNumber");
            PN.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(java.lang.Long.toString(PhoneNumber)));
            contact.appendChild(PN);

        }
        /**
        *
        * The function WriteToXMLFile is responsible for writing the data into output XML file "PhoneBook.xml".
        * WriteToXMLFile also formats the data to be written into pretty print way with INDENT spaces and line breaks etc.
        */
        void WriteToXMLFile() throws Exception{

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
            source = new DOMSource(doc);
            result = new StreamResult(new File(filePathString));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            System.out.println("Contact Saved !");

        }
        /**
        *
        * The function UpdateXMLFile updates the existing XML file with the new user data.
        * The new set of user data gets a unique id for the element "Contact" which is calculated and generated by UpdateXMLFile.
        * 
        */
        void UpdateXMLFile() throws Exception{

            doc = docBuilder.parse(filePathString);
            int AttrValue=1;
            Node ContactInfo = doc.getFirstChild();
            NodeList NumberChildNodes = ContactInfo.getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0;i<NumberChildNodes.getLength();i++)
                {            
                    Node n = NumberChildNodes.item(i);
                    if ("Contact".equals(n.getNodeName())) 
                        {
                            AttrValue+=1;
                        }     
                }     
            Element contact = doc.createElement("Contact");
            ContactInfo.appendChild(contact);
            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue(Integer.toString(AttrValue));
            contact.setAttributeNode(attr);
            Element firstname = doc.createElement("FirstName");
            firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(FirstName));
            contact.appendChild(firstname);
            Element lastname = doc.createElement("LastName");
            lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(LastName));
            contact.appendChild(lastname);
            Element PN = doc.createElement("PhoneNumber");
            PN.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(java.lang.Long.toString(PhoneNumber)));
            contact.appendChild(PN);

        }


    }
```

Class ErrorHandler :

```
    package xmlphonebook;

    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import java.lang.NumberFormatException;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class ErrorHandler extends Exception{

        ErrorHandler(Exception e){

            if(e.toString().contains("NumberFormatException"))
            {   System.out.println("Enter information corractly");
            }else if(e.toString().contains("ParserConfigurationException"))
            {   System.out.println("Doc builder Error"); 
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }else if(e.toString().contains("TransformerException"))
            {   System.out.println("Transformation Error between source and result ");
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }else if(e.toString().contains("SAXException"))
            {   System.out.println("Doc Builder Error in UpdateXMLFile function");
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }else if(e.toString().contains("IOException"))
            {   System.out.println("IO Exception Error");
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }else{
                e.printStackTrace();
            }      

        }
    }
```

**Output :**

```
Enter Your FirstName = 
xxxxxxxx
Enter Your LastName = 
yyyyyyyy
Enter Your PhoneNumber = 
7896456123693
```

**Error :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at xmlphonebook.StoreContactInformation.WriteToXMLFile(StoreContactInformation.java:105)
at xmlphonebook.StoreContactInformation.<init>(StoreContactInformation.java:65)
at xmlphonebook.XMLPhoneBook.storeContactInfo(XMLPhoneBook.java:35)
at xmlphonebook.XMLPhoneBook.main(XMLPhoneBook.java:43)
```

**Function that causes the Error:**

```
 void WriteToXMLFile() throws Exception{

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        source = new DOMSource(doc);
        result = new StreamResult(new File(filePathString));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("Contact Saved !");

    }
```

**Please tell me what mistake I am doing**.

Comment: Weird naming! Your getters are void and update the object by calling setters! And why are you using that many instance fields instead of local variables? This makes it very hard to argue about object state, which might now be the reason why you cannot tell the cause of your NPE.

Comment: I guess this is your line number 105, `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");`, In the constructor I don't see `transformer` variable being initialized. May be this helps, `transformer=TransformerFactory.newTransformer()`

Comment: @Shrikant Havale I tired that already and still the same.

Comment: @isnot2bad sorry about the bad programming, I am very new to this.

Comment: well then, can you tell us which is your line number 105

Comment: @Shrikant Havale      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

Answer (score 1):

I copied all your classes in my workspace, and indeed there is NPE, but as I mentioned in one of my previous comments,
`transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");`
`transformer` is `NULL`, I checked it out by debugging and keeping a break point  and used the same solution to fix it as mentioned in my comment.

This is how I resolved it, in your constructor

```
    StoreContactInformation(String fn, String ln, long pn) throws Exception {
        filePathString="PhoneBook.xml"; //File Path is the current working directory. 
        f = new File(filePathString);
        FirstName=fn;
        LastName=ln;
        PhoneNumber=pn;
        docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        /******* added this line ******************/
        transformer=transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
        /******* added this line ******************/

        // check if the XML file exist already !        
        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            //if exist
            UpdateXMLFile();
            WriteToXMLFile(); 
        }else{
            //if do not exist
            CreateXMLFile(); 
            WriteToXMLFile();
        } 
    }
```

And got this output,

> Enter Your FirstName =  xxxx
>
> Enter Your LastName =  yyyy
>
> Enter Your PhoneNumber =  123456
>
> Contact Saved !